# Jenkins declarative pipeline lock current JenkinsAgent (env.NODE_NAME)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to lock the current Agent (env.NODE_NAME) for all of stages in the Pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent any
options{
    lock (
    resource: '${env.NODE_NAME}',
    quantity: 1,
    skipIfLocked: true
    )
}

stages{
    stage('stage') {
        steps {
            echo "Something"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Log:

```
Trying to acquire lock on [${env.NODE_NAME}]
Resource [${env.NODE_NAME}] did not exist. Created.
Lock acquired on [${env.NODE_NAME}]
```

Comment: Doing it in the options block looks like the right way to go. You'll want to change the single quotes to double quotes to expand `env.NODE_NAME`, though that might also not work, because I think options is evaluated before entering the agent. Give that a shot though and see if it comes out correctly or as null.

Comment: ...Running on agent_TEST in /home/TEST/jenkins-agent/workspace/Test_PIPE...Trying to acquire lock on [null]
Resource [null] did not exist. Created.
Lock acquired on [null]

Comment: Yeah, so it looks like env isn't available in options. Are you able to pass that NODE_NAME in some other way? Maybe with `${currentBuild.getRawBuild().getExecutor().getOwner().getDisplayName()}`?

Comment: ${currentBuild.getRawBuild().getExecutor().getOwner().getDisplayName()} return master. But the Pipeline is runing on: Running on agent_TEST in /home/TEST/jenkins-agent/workspace/Test_PIPE

Comment: Hmm, so maybe that block executes before the build hits the agent. I'm not sure how else to find that without env, but poking around at the javadocs might help you find the right methods to call: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html